# Is there a good method for choosing which cards to use in Deluxe Illuminati?

Tags: illuminati

I have played Deluxe Illuminati from the beginning, and have all the original expansions and the Y2K expansion.  The problem is that when playing with Y2K, you end up with too many cards in the deck.

Does anyone have a good way of deciding which cards to use?  Is there an official method?

Comment: Steve Jackson games are good at that -- my decks of Chez Geek and Munchkin *almost* require a mechanical shuffler from the decks being so huge.

Comment: @Little BT: actually they are quite *bad* at that; Munchkin is definitely not a good game, but if you add the expansions it becomes even more unplayable. I also wonder how Hacker would look like without the (now-embedded) expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I use a very targeted set of cards, for example, having lots of power zero cards, in a game where the player who loves playing Cthulu gets on everybody's nerves.

You can build sets of cards geared for more income, remove all the non-group cards, and anything that comes to mind.

But I cannot be bothered. Sometimes I'll remove some cards that just seem to water down the deck, but other than that, I really do use a mechanical shuffler like LittleBobbyTables says, and then I just take the top 50-100 cards off the top, and we use those. The games end up being random enough.

Answer (score 1):

I have only the Deluxe set, but one thing that we've done is use multiple stacks to draw from. After shuffling the cards, cut the deck into several stacks. Whenever someone draws, they choose which stack they draw from. That way, if you start to get a run of basic set cards, you can try another pile and possibly get something different.

It may not actually be making a difference, but it seems like you see more variety of cards that way.